# How to pass value of a field from one model to another model in Odoo, when they are present in same view?

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, odoo-10

I have view for `A` model which contain following fields

1. Student_name field `many2one`
2. x_course_id field `many2one`
3. `one2many` field named 'b_ids' which refer `B` model.

`b_ids` is made as a tree in same view which contains following fields

1. some_field_name `many2one`
2. x_course_id field `many2one`
3. a_id field `many2one` which refer `A` model

Now, the problem is that the field `some_field_name` must be listed according to the value of `course_id` field which should be same as `course_id field in`A`model`.

I related field for course_id as

[image]

It is fetching value after saving that record, because of which my domain for `some_field_name` doesn't works

domain for `some_field_name` is written as [('x_course_id','=' x_course_id)]

But since this `x_course_id` on right hand side doesn't exist before saving the form, this domain doesn't works.

So, i wanted to know, is there a way by which i can get value of `x_course_id` in tree before saving the form.

Can any of the following fields be helpful in these case?? If yes, how?

[image]

Comment: So essentially, you want to change a domain after a field was changed on your view ?

Comment: Yes, something like that. Actually whats happening is that when i select a student the course related to him is automatically filled and and i want that course value in my domain, so that i can select 'some_field_name' field according to the course that is auto filled. The 'some_field_name' being many2one provides me with a list and i want that list to be according the course field.

Comment: I've found a solution for odoo-8, but it wouldn't work as is for odoo 9/10. What I've done is essentially deleting then recreating all the fields with the same values (except the one updated) in the `b_ids` in an `@onchange` in model A. Since for the front end, new lines were added, then an `onchange` is triggered and the domain was properly set by an `@onchange` in model B returning a domain. You should try to do something similar, but I cannot do it since I'm still running odoo  Well if I get some time to kill, I may set up an odoo 10 to try it. I can post my answer for odoo 8 if you want.

Comment: Thank you. Your response is appreciable. Please post your answer for odoo 8. Though i completed it with a different strategy, i am sure that i will get to learn some interesting things form your answer. So, please post it.